# Derivative question involving table and function

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Consider the given function and table.

ℎ() =()/(2 − ())

x = 1, f(1) = 3, f'(1)=2

x = 3, f(3) = -5, f'(3) = 7

a) Determine the equation of the tangent line to the graph of () at  = 1.

b) Is () continuous at  = 2? Justify your response.

c) Use the intermediate value theorem to justify the existence of a zero on the interval [1,3].

d) Determine ℎ′(3).

[Picture of chart and function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqz0H.png)

Comment: Hi, sorry but it's going to be difficult to give appropriate help without seeing more of what you've tried, or your thoughts on the problem. Can you tell us more about what you know, what you've tried, or where you're confused, so we can point you in the right direction? It really helps to have a jumping-off point to go from.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, honestly I am super confused  as to what to do. I tried finding the equation for f'(x) but after 2 hours I couldn't find it. Also in the table the 3rd value in the table should be the derivative of f(x), so f(1) = 2 and f(3) = 7. I tried graphing too but that didn't get me anywhere. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: We actually don't need the formula for $f$ in this case, the given values actually give us all of the information about the behavior of f that we would need.